# Find first number greater than x and return another value in that row

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

I have created an investment spreadsheet. In one column I have the ending balance each year. In another column I have the years.

```
 A    B
2000 500K
2001 450K
2003 1.2M
2004 1.5M
```

How can I display the year I hit a certain arbitrary threshold (say $1M) in a single cell somewhere else on the sheet (say E32), without knowing how long it may take to reach the amount?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we can make the assumption (as presented) that years are in column A and amounts are in column B, this **array formula** will work in any cell that's not in column A or B (such as E32).

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(TRUE,B:B>=1000000,0)),B:B,0))
```

For array formulas, type it in and CSE - press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will display the formula with curly brackets around it.

On OSX, an array formula is input like this-

> Select the range, press <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>RETURN</kbd>.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26605268/array-formula-on-excel-for-mac/26605282#26605282)

Comment: Ok. This helps and I think will work! But how can I display the FIRST year ONLY in a single cell that isn't in the same row as the correlating info. For example, using your example above since the account hits $1000 in 2002 how could display "2002" in let's just say cell E32? So that there doesn't have to be a whole list, just the first year the account reaches that amount.

Comment: @Jared try the new one, it can go in E32 or.. wherever, assuming years are in A:A and money is in B:B

Comment: Awesome! That did it!!! Thanks so much!!! I've been trying to figure this out all day!

Comment: @Jared if this solves your problem please click the green checkmark next to the answer to mark your question as solved.

Comment: Thanks for this. This question shows up high on Google for the relevant query and exactly solved my problem :)

Comment: @Brandon good to hear it!